# pre calc question:How much is it worth after t years?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The value of an automobile depreciates. It is originally worth $40,000 but then it loses one tenth of its value every year.

(a) How much is it worth at the end of the first year?
36000
(b) How much is it worth after 3 years?
29160
I know how to do a and b

(c) How much is it worth after t years?
I don't know how to do c!!!
Answer is 40,000(0.9)^t dolars

this equation may help but i don't know how to use it:
$N(t)=N_{initial}e^{kt}$

Comment: The equation you mentioned: N(t)=N initial*e^(k*t) is useful for **continually** depreciating or compounding values. Since this is depreciating on a yearly basis, you are fine to use the equation mentioned by LAcarguy.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_t$ be the value of the car after $t$ years. We have: $A_0 = 40,000$, $A_1 = (1 - 0.1)A_0 = 0.9A_0$, and continue: $A_2 = 0.9A_1 = 0.9(0.9A_0) = 0.9^2A_0$. So we generalize this:

$A_t = 0.9^tA_0 = 40,000\cdot 0.9^t$